# A perpendicular line to a plane in 3D

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I have two line segments identified by two end points each. Two line segments are in the same plane and intersecting at a point. I would like to draw a line (normal of the plane) passing through the intersection point. I use `TikZ`, `calc`, and `3d` libraries. But I couldn't figure out a straightforward way to do that. I can calculate the line (normal) end point using Matlab software. But I prefer `TikZ` solution, if it is possible.

Edit 1: Minimum Working Example

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x  = {(-0.5cm,-0.5cm)},
                    y  = {(0.9659cm,-0.25882cm)},
                    z  = {(0cm,1cm)},
                    scale = 0.8,
                    color = {lightgray}]

% the data input is created for minimal working example
\coordinate (A) at (1,1,4);
\coordinate (B) at (7,5,4);
\coordinate (SS) at (5,11/3,4);
\coordinate (C) at (7,1,7);
\coordinate (D) at ($(C)!7cm!(SS)$);

% two line segments
\draw[black] (A) -- (B);
\draw[black] (C) -- (D);

% intersection point (SS = S)
\coordinate (S) at (intersection of A--B and C--D);
\filldraw[green] (S) circle(2pt);

%% the plane
\draw[dashed,black,fill=red!30, opacity=0.5] (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- (D) -- cycle;

% labels
\node[above] at (A) {$A$};
\node[below] at (B) {$B$};
\node[left] at (C) {$C$};
\node[right] at (D) {$D$};
\node[right] at (S) {$S$};

% how to draw a line segment starting at (S) pointing outward
% and being perpendicular to the plane (A,B,C,D) ?

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the `intersections` library might help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a proof of concept, followed by discussion.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x  = {(-0.5cm,-0.5cm)},
                    y  = {(0.9659cm,-0.25882cm)},
                    z  = {(0cm,1cm)},
                    scale = 0.8,
                    color = {lightgray}]

% the data input is created for minimal working example
\newdimen\Ax
\newdimen\Ay
\newdimen\Az
\Ax=1pt
\Ay=1pt
\Az=4pt

\coordinate (A) at (\Ax,\Ay,\Az);

\newdimen\Bx
\newdimen\By
\newdimen\Bz
\Bx=7pt
\By=5pt
\Bz=4pt

\coordinate (B) at (\Bx,\By,\Bz);

\newdimen\SSx
\newdimen\SSy
\newdimen\SSz
\SSx=5pt
\SSy=\dimexpr11pt/3\relax
\SSz=4pt

\coordinate (SS) at (\SSx,\SSy,\SSz);

\newdimen\Cx
\newdimen\Cy
\newdimen\Cz
\Cx=7pt
\Cy=1pt
\Cz=7pt

\coordinate (C) at (\Cx,\Cy,\Cz);

\newdimen\Dx
\newdimen\Dy
\newdimen\Dz
% D = t*SS + (1-t)*C; t=1.7
\Dx=\dimexpr1.7\SSx-0.7\Cx\relax
\Dy=\dimexpr1.7\SSy-0.7\Cy\relax
\Dz=\dimexpr1.7\SSz-0.7\Cz\relax

\coordinate (D) at (\Dx,\Dy,\Dz);

\newdimen\Nx
\newdimen\Ny
\newdimen\Nz
\Nx=\dimexpr(\By-\Ay)/100*(\Dz-\Cz)/100-(\Bz-\Az)/100*(\Dy-\Cy)/100\relax
\Ny=\dimexpr(\Bz-\Az)/100*(\Dx-\Cx)/100-(\Bx-\Ax)/100*(\Dz-\Cz)/100\relax
\Nz=\dimexpr(\Bx-\Ax)/100*(\Dy-\Cy)/100-(\By-\Ay)/100*(\Dx-\Cx)/100\relax

% two line segments
\draw[black] (A) -- (B);
\draw[black] (C) -- (D);

% intersection point (SS = S)
\coordinate (S) at (intersection of A--B and C--D);
\filldraw[green] (S) circle(2pt);

%% the plane
\draw[dashed,black,fill=red!30, opacity=0.5] (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- (D) -- cycle;

% labels
\node[above] at (A) {$A$};
\node[below] at (B) {$B$};
\node[left] at (C) {$C$};
\node[right] at (D) {$D$};
\node[right] at (S) {$S$};

% how to draw a line segment starting at (S) pointing outward
% and being perpendicular to the plane (A,B,C,D) ?

\coordinate (N) at ($(S)+0.01*(\Nx,\Ny,\Nz)$);
\node[right] at (N) {$N$};
\draw[->] (S) -- (N);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem with `tikz` is that it doesn't do three-dimensional geometry.  Any expression such as `(1,5,2)` is converted directly to a point in the plane, as `1 * xvector + 5 * yvector + 3 * zvector`, where `xvector` in your example is `(-0.5cm,-0.5cm)`, etc.  This means that much of the three-dimensional inforamtion is lost at the stage when you use the `\coordinate` command to define `(A)` and the other points.

In particular, the projections `(A)`,...,`(D)` in your code are not sufficient to determine the normal.  E.g. if the 3d points `A`,...,`D` all sat in the plane of the page, the normal would point directly out towards us, on the other hand if `A` and `D` were a long way in front of the page, but `C` and `B` in the page, the normal would be close to parallel to the page.

So, assuming that you wanted to put in different 3d points to get similar such a diagrams, I have set up each point via new variables `\Ax`,`\Ay`,`\Az`, and then used those coordinates in the subsequent calculations and assignments.

You had point `D` defined as a certain distance along the line `C--SS`, I replaced that by a certain proportion, rather than starting to calculate distances in 3d.  (The calculation you had was `7cm` in the plane.)

Now given `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` in three-dimensions, the normal is specified via the cross product of the difference vectors: if `(vx,vy,vz) = B - A`, `(wx,wy,wz) = D - C` then the normal is

```
(vy*wz-vz-wy, vz*wx-vx*wz, vx*wy-vy*wx)
```

I put this into `\Nx`,`\Ny`,`\Nz` - but had to scale, because of arithmetic overflow.  Once one has this normal, one can use the standard `calc` mechanisms to draw an arrow in that direction starting from `(S)`.  Again I scaled, so the arrow was a reasonable size.

Comment: Nice answer! Four comments: (A) I guess `(1,5,2)` is converted to `1 * xvector + 5 * yvector + 2 * zvector`, isn’t it? (B) Is there a reason that you dont use `pgfmath` to calculate the cross product? (C) could you add a bigger image (too big images will be scaled to fit the width …). (D) I’d use `\def\Ax{1pt}` since it’s shorter or `\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ax}{1}` to use `pgfmath` consequently.

Comment: @Tobi (A) Thanks for spotting the typo.  (B) `pgfmath` would be a good way to go; this was just proof of concept.  (C) Is this new image big enough?

Comment: (C) Yes, big enough :-)