# how to get x,y and z components of a coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to be able to use `x`, `y` and `z` components of a defined coordinate in `TikZ` to reuse the values somewhere else in my code. For example, let's have something like,

```
\coordinate (p1) at (-2.6,0.7,0);
```

I would like to do something like as below,

```
\coordinate (p11) at (p1_x,p1_y,12);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can do this for `x` and `y`, but not for `z`.  TikZ converts 3D coordinates to 2D at time of entry and does not remember the original data so cannot reconstruct it later.

Comment: Generally I found it _easier_ to handle my own 3D projections via custom coordinate systems. In that way you retain much of the flexibility of `TikZ` which is not always obtainable in the regular 3D coordinate system.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54804/86 as I think it covers the same question.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your comments. So this seems to be a problem and I'd like to know what is the solution for? Any workaround?

Comment: Can you give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to play with?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98213/15925 for a proof of concept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, while a solution is impossible for the general case (for the reasons Andrew explained in a comment), a solution for this particular case is possible, via a horrible, horrible, hack.

The problem is that, as soon as you set something like:

```
\coordinate (p) at (3,4,5);
```

tikz computes the projection of the 3D point `(3,4,5)`, according to the current values of keys `x`, `y` and `z`, and gets a 2D point, whose coordinates are stored in `(p)`. So the final value for the coordinates stored in `(p)` are in absolute units (pt) and of course they are not 3 and 4.

**But** in this particular case, coordinate `p1` has z=0:

```
\coordinate (p1) at (3,4,0);
```

so for this point the computed coordinates *should be* equal to the ones given, i.e: 3 and 4. But there is a problem, they are stored in absolute units (pt in this case). Tikz multiplies 3 (and 4) by the value of the key `x` (and `y`) which are 1cm by default, and the result expressed in `pt` is what `(p1)` gets. So, using `let...in` construct we can extract those values, but they will be in points.

So the horrible, horrible hack is to define `x` and `y` to be equal to 1pt, so that the figure uses points instead of cm as default units. This works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt, y=1pt, z=-0.5pt]  % Agh
% Let's draw some 3D axes
\coordinate (x) at (100,0,0);
\coordinate (y) at (0,100,0);
\coordinate (z) at (0,0,100);
\foreach \axis in {x,y,z}
   \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (\axis);

% Our point
\coordinate (p1) at (80, 30, 0);
% Compute the point at the same x,y, elevated 25pt in z
\path let \p1 = (p1)
         in coordinate (p11) at (\x1, \y1, 25);

% Draw those points
\fill[red]     (p1) circle (1pt);
\fill[blue]   (p11) circle (1pt);
% Some bells and whistles
\draw[dotted] (p1) -- (p1|-x);
\draw[dotted] (p1) -- (p1-|y);
\draw[dashed,-latex] (p1) -- (p11);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Results in:

[image: Result]